# Where should I post a question about ♏

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The minim symbol is an m with a long tail on its lower right, crossed by an x. In Unicode, it's combined with the Scorpio astrological sign and, on Macs, that is inexplicably forced into a disgusting emoji-style icon even in plain running text.

The symbol itself is an English or language question but, since I'm curious about how to format the CSS or HTML to force my Mac to display it in a less obnoxious form, I suppose it's really a question for one of the computing subs. But which one is appropriate? Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

> The symbol itself is an English or language question but,

Since you're curious about **how to format the CSS or HTML** to force your Mac to display it in a less obnoxious form, I suppose it's really a question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Because it's a valid **practical programming question**, Stack Overflow will accept it. However as a regular notice, I suggest that you search for similar questions in case it's a duplicate.

Comment: My best bet would be that SO says "it can't be fixed" and moves on

Answer (score 6):

It depends in what context you want to know about changing their display...

You mention HTML & CSS so your question may be OK on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) has a number of emoji display issue questions so may be more appropriate if your question is more generally about their display. A similar example:

- [How to stop unicode glyphs displaying as "emoji" in MS Word 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1207541/how-to-stop-unicode-glyphs-displaying-as-emoji-in-ms-word-2016/1208736#1208736)

If your question is more macOS specific (and less programming specific) you may want to post on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). A similar question there:

- [Why do emoji like 💩 appear when I use Safari, but not Chrome?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/41228/155896)

I'm not familiar with either so make sure to check the relevant help pages to make sure your question is on-topic and search through existing questions first.